# Removing Both Ends of a String in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, match

I have a Google Sheet which is constantly being populated via a Zapier zap. In one of the columns, I receive a PayPal "descriptor" which contains a unique identifier I need to do some look ups on other tabs within the same document.

Can someone point me in the direction of the correct REGEX to use to strip off the front and end of the string, for example:

```
Annual Fee-66421763-07142022191540
```

I would like to just have the piece in between the hyphens so the output reads simply:

```
66421763
```

Now, the front section will likely always read the same, the middle (the piece I want to extract) will be different and could change length too, as will the end section after the dash.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "-(\d+)-")
```